Emulate ObservableProperty from Community Toolkit MVVM
I'd like to be able to emulate the behaviour of Community Toolkit MVVM's ObservableProperty attribute where it basically generates a property from a field with a PropertyChanged invoke on its set.
The main reason I'd like to do this is that I fint it useful for more than WPF applications and I dont really need everything else that comes with the toolkit.
How could I write an attribute class that does that, ideally without having to build everytime (like Community Toolkit MVVM does)?
Thanks for the help!

There's no question here (?)

@Blindy I edited my question, let me know if anything is unclear

An "attribute class" does not generate code like a source generators does. It sounds like you want to create a source generator.

You might also try something like Fody PropertyChanged:  https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged
